# Why does this nested loop have O(n) time complexity?

Tags: c, time-complexity

I have a test in computer sience about complexity and I have this question:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j = j * i) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

My solution is O(nlogn) because the first `for` is n-2 and the second `for` is doing log in base i of n and it's n-2 * logn, that is O(nlogn)-

But my teacher told us it's n and when I tried in cLion to run it it gives me 2*n and it's O(n). Can someone explain why it is O(n)?

Comment: What do you need help with? You have already learned that it's O(n).

Comment: @mkrieger1, By why. The OP is looking for an explanation.

Comment: @OleMorud - No, this is `log_2(n) + log_3(n) + ... + log_n(n)`

Comment: @UrielZylbermann my bad you're right

Comment: @mkrieger1 iwant to know how to show its O(n) on a test

Comment: @OleMorud you not right...

Comment: @UrielZylbermann so how this is O(n)

Comment: Almost exactly the same question a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75215349/what-is-the-correct-time-complexity-for-this-following-code

Answer (score 2):

Empirically, you can see that this is correct (that's around the right value for the sum of the series), for [n=100](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28log_i%28100%29%29%2C+i%3D2+to+99) and [n=1,000](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28log_i%281000%29%29%2C+i%3D2+to+999)

If you want more intuition, you can think about the fact that for nearly all the series, `i > sqrt(n)`.

for example, if `n = 100` then 90% of values have `i > 10`, and for `n = 1,000` 97% have `i > 32`.

From that point onwards, all iterations of the outer loop will have at most 2 iterations in the inner loop (since `log(n)` with base `sqrt(n)` is 2, by definition).

If `n` grows really large, you can also apply the same logic to show that from the cube root to the square root, log is between 2 and 3, etc...

Comment: so how in a test can i show that because i tried to do sigma of log base i on n
i did logn / logi and took out the log n out from the sigma 
after this i have sigma of n-2 of 1/ logi and its O(nlogn) no ?

Answer (score 0):

This *would* be O(nlogn) if `j` was incremented by `i` each iteration, not multiplied by it. As it is now, the `j` loop increases much more slowly than `n` grows, which is why your teacher and CLion state the time complexity as O(n).

Comment: why would it be O(n log n) if `j` was incremented by `i` each iteration?

Comment: I'm personally not too familiar with log in the sense of loops, but I determined it to be true empirically using large `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's `j=j*i`, not `j=j*2`. That means most of the time, the inner loop will only have one pass. For example, with `n` of 33, the inner loop will only have one pass when `i` is in [7,33).

```
n = 33

j = 32
j = 16
j =  8 27
j =  4  9 16 25
j =  2  3  4  5  6
j =  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1      1   1
--------------------------------------------
i =  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 ... 28  29
```

If you think of the above as a graph, it looks like the complexity of algorithm is O( area under [1/log(n)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1%2Fln%28x%29+for+x%3D1+to+20) ). I have no idea how to prove that, and calculating that integral involves the unfamiliar-to-me [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). But the Wikipedia page does say this function is O( n / log n ).

---

Let's do it experimentally.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
   for ( int n = 20; n <= 20000; ++n ) {
      int counter = 0;
      for ( int i = 2; i < n; ++i ) {
         for ( int j = 1; j < n ; j *= i ) {
            ++counter;
         }
      }

      if ( n % 1000 == 0 )
         printf( "%d: %.3f\n", n, counter / (n-1) );
   }
}
```

```
1000: 2.047
2000: 2.033
3000: 2.027
4000: 2.023
5000: 2.021
6000: 2.019
7000: 2.017
8000: 2.016
9000: 2.015
10000: 2.014
11000: 2.013
12000: 2.013
13000: 2.012
14000: 2.012
15000: 2.011
16000: 2.011
17000: 2.011
18000: 2.010
19000: 2.010
20000: 2.010
```

So it doubles plus a little. But the extra little *shrinks* as `n` grows. So it's definitely not O( n log n ). It's something of the form O( n / f(n) ), where f() produces some number ≥1. It looks like it could be O( n / log n ), but that's pure speculation.

---

Whatever f(n) is, O( n / f(n) ) approaches O( n ) as n approaches infinity. So we can also call this O( n ).

Comment: so how in a test can i show that because i tried to do sigma of log base i on n i did logn / logi and took out the log n out from the sigma after this i have sigma of n-2 of 1/ logi and its O(nlogn) no ?

Comment: `log n` *grows* as `n` increases. But I showed the factor *shrinks* as `n` increases. It's not `log n`. Looks more like `1/log n`.

Comment: you right this its what i got logn * sigma of k=2 until n-1  of 1/logk

Answer (score 0):

For some value of `i`, `j` will go like

```
1  i^1  i^2  i^3  ....
```

So the number of times the inner loop needs to execute is found like

```
log_i(n)
```

which would lead to the following:

```
log_2(n) + log_3(n) + log_4(n) + ....
```

**But**... there is the stop condition `j < n` which need to be considered.

Now consider `n` as a number that can be written as `m^2`. As soon a `i` reach the value `m` all remaining inner loop iterations will only be done for `j` equal `1` and `j` equal `i` (because i^2 will be greater than `n`). In other words - there will only be 2 executions of the inner loop.

So the total number of iterations will be:

```
2 * (m^2 - m) + number_of_iteration(i=2:m)
```

Now divide that by `n` which is `m^2`:

```
(2 * (m^2 - m) + number_of_iteration(i=2:m)) / m^2
```

gives

```
2 * (1 -1/m) + number_of_iteration(i=2:m) / m^2
```

The first part `2 * (1 -1/m)` clear goes towards 2 as `m` goes to inifinity.

The second part is (at worst):

```
 (log_2(n) + log_3(n) + log_4(n) + ... + log_m(n)) / m^2
```

or

```
 (log_2(n) + log_3(n) + log_4(n) + ... + log_m(n)) / n
```

As `log(x)/x` goes towards zero as `x` goes towards infinity, the above expression will also go towards zero.

So the full expression:

```
(2 * (m^2 - m) + number_of_iteration(i=2:m)) / m^2
```

will go towards 2 as `m` goes towards infinity.

In other words: The total number of iterations divided by `n` will go towards 2. Consequently we have O(n).